# X-Cart Shipping Address Validation

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, x-cart

Does anyone know the best way to implement address validation in X-Cart? Validation should block a user from being able to continue in the order process until a valid shipping address is set. Maybe there is a service I could use to perform this validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe UPS offers this service...
http://www.ups.com/content/us/en/bussol/browse/addressvalidationstreetlevel.html